# Cannot do POST in IBM BPM to web service

Tags: ibm-bpm

I'm new to IBM BPM and am trying to put together a process that sends a `POST` request to a RESTful web service using `teamworks.HttpClient`.

I am able to `POST` via Chrome's Advanced REST Client, so I know the server and service are accessible from my system.

When I try to do this via `teamworks.HttpClient` in Process Designer I get `HTTP Status 405`.  I've only ever seen that when I screwed up and specified `GET`.

I have written Ajax calls in JavaScript to access this service.  I have had to specify `POST` in the Ajax calls.

Is `teamworks.HttpClient` configured to be a `GET` or `POST` by default?  If it does `GET`, how can I tell it to do a `POST`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you did, your assumption is correct: teamworks.HttpClient fires a HTTP GET by default. As far as I know, there is no way of configuring it to send a POST request.

I would recommend writing your own Java Integration Service with a more capable web client, this will be really handy for the future anyways:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/bpm/bpmjournal/1404_boyer/1404_boyer.html

This resource includes writing your own REST Server, but at the bottom there is also a chapter about implementing a REST Client as a Java Integration Service.